# Calling a method in ruby from a method with the same name

Tags: ruby

I know that this is a BAD PRACTICE, but I found something, and I want to understand more of the method calling mechanisms in ruby.

Recently I was creating a class, and I named a method print. Inside that **print**, I called the standard **print**, and obviously, I had issues. When I found that I had a name conflict, I knew immediately that the right solution was to change my **print** to another name, but a doubt born in my soul: if for any reason I really NEEDED to maintain the name **print**, how can I call the standard ruby **print** inside MY method **print**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `print` this is generally `Kernel.print`. The reason you do not need to explicitly add the receiver `Kernel` is because the `Kernel` module is included in `Object` (base class for most objects in ruby).

In your case you have defined a `print` method in your own class and thus if you would like to use `Kernel#print` you have 2 options, you can either :

- Explicitly call `Kernel.print` (probably preferred for this implementation); or
- Call `super` to pass this up the hierarchy chain (until it hits another `print` method which would generally be `Kernel#print`)

Example:

```
class MyObject
  def print(val)
    Kernel.print "#{val} called with Kernel.print" 
    puts
    super "#{val} print passed up the hierarchy chain" 
  end 
end 

o = MyObject.new
o.print('engineersmnky') 
# engineersmnky called with Kernel.print
# engineersmnky print passed up the hierarchy chain 
#=> nil
```

Comment: ...recalling that [Kernel#print](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print) does nothing more than call [IO#print](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-i-print) on the receiver `$stdout`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland true there are other alternatives technically speaking but they get uglier and uglier the further we move away from the 2 suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` method is defined on the [`Kernel` module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print) so you could call it like
`Kernel.print('Hello, world!')`